How do I infer first generic function type from parameter and specify the second?
The below example function myDesiredFunction returns a function that takes a function X as an argument. Function X should take two parameters. The first of these parameters should have its type inferred from the argument passed to myDesiredFunction. The second argument should be able to be specified through a generic type passed to myDesiredFunction. How can I achieve this?
interface TypeOne {
    key: string;
}

interface TypeTwo {
    value: string;
}

// how far I got

const myFunction = <const T extends TypeOne>(parameter: T) => { 
    // I don't want to have to define TypeTwo here explicitly, but when the user calls this function
    return (functionArgument: (argumentOne: TypeOne, argumentTwo: TypeTwo) => null) => {
        console.log(functionArgument);
    }
}

const myTest = myFunction({key: "test"})((argumentOne, argumentTwo) => null);


// what I'd like

interface TypeTwoExtended extends TypeTwo {
    secondValue: string;
}


const myDesiredFunction = <const T extends TypeOne, U extends TypeTwo>(parameter: T) => { 
    return (functionArgument: (argumentOne: TypeOne, argumentTwo: U) => null) => {
        console.log(functionArgument);
    }
}

// argumentOne should be of type TypeOne, and argumentTwo should be of type TypeTwoExtended
const myDesiredTest = myDesiredFunction<TypeTwoExtended>({key: "test"})((argumentOne, argumentTwo) => null);


According to how you use it, U extends TypeTwo should be a generic type of the returned function
const myDesiredFunction = <const T extends TypeOne>(parameter: T) => { 
    // Shouldn't `argumentOne` be of type `T` ?
    return <U extends TypeTwo>(functionArgument: (argumentOne: TypeOne, argumentTwo: U) => null) => {
        console.log(functionArgument);
    }
}

// argumentOne is of type `TypeOne`, argumentTwo of type `TypeTwoExtended`
const myDesiredTest = myDesiredFunction({key: "test"})<TypeTwoExtended>((argumentOne, argumentTwo) => null);

And of course if argumentTwo is already of type TypeTwoExtended, you won't need to specifically types it :)


Your function myFunction returns another function that accepts a callback. This callback should use the specified generic types T and U for its parameters:

return (functionArgument: (argumentOne: T, argumentTwo: U) => void) => {...}


When invoking myDesiredFunction you should explicitly set both T and U:

const myDesiredTest = myDesiredFunction<TypeOne, TypeTwoExtended>({key: "test"})((argumentOne, argumentTwo) => null)

